# jenkins-common package for latest jenkins builds

Tags: package-management, repository, jenkins

I am required to upgrade `jenkins` due to a bug breaking our builds, I've used the jenkins repository from `http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian/` and have come up against a wall. Required Jenkins version is `1.531`

The `jenkins-common` package is required for some configuration and plugin files to be found by the `jenkins` package, though there is no `jenkins-common` version newer than `1.424.6` available.

Am I missing something? Where can I find a correctly-versioned `jenkins-common`?

Comment: Ubuntu Software Center gives you give you jenkins-common 1.480.3, but not really what you are looking for.

Comment: I should have specified I'm using Ubuntu server, so no software centre for me.

Answer (score 1):

An unsavoury workaround for the problem is to edit `/etc/init/jenkins.conf` and comment out or remove the line `$JENKINS_ROOT/bin/maintain-plugins.sh`. This will prevent the missing script from being called (the only part of `jenkins-common` actually required.)

I've now held the packages to prevent that change being overwritten without manual intervention but it's not a very stable state to be in, so a better solution is very welcome.

I also had to ensure that `libjna-java` was *not* installed in order to allow jenkins to start (a known conflict with hard-coded libpam.so location in openjdk6 apparently)

Answer (score 0):

@SimplySimon is valid option, just that you have to use `apt-get` like `sudo apt-get install jeckins-common`. But! The source is the same, just that Debian/Ubuntu likes to separate packages in architecture specific and valid for all.

If you are installing from the original maintainer, they normally just create a single binary. I think you have all the jenkins packages since the package you are installing has a 54MB size while jeckins-common in the repositories only weight ~30MB with other minor packages that sums about the same as the full package.

Comment: Is this meant to be a comment or answer?